# interactive_marker execution error

Tags: ros, rosmake, visualization-msgs, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello;
After I've tried to create the *interactive_markers* package and copied all the folders from the source which are needed for the package from *interactive_markers* for **electric**. I got an error when I tried to build the package which is running the rosmake for this package. The error is:

> ~ros/interactive_markers/src/interactive_marker_server.cpp:431:
> error:  ‘visualization_msgs’ has not
> been declared ...

There are some other errors which is kind of related to the *interactive_marker_server.cpp*, but I do not paste it here.

So, what I wanna ask here, as it seems the package is **new in electric**, someone might have encountered this. Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49632/interactive_marker-execution-error/) by [nufa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3433/nufa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error suggests you are missing some includes which include "visualization_msgs".  You'll need to provide more information to get more help.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0